# Eclipse integration from application, not plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

For this question, assume that Java code (domain classes) exist for some problem domain for which no tools are available in Eclipse. One could then write a "rich client" based on the Eclipse platform to provide tools. Assuming that the tools are intended to be used by developers, an Eclipse plugin (instead of a full rich client) will do.

Building an Eclipse plugin has disadvantages. Most notably: Long development cycles. Anyone who wants to develop the tools has to dive into plugin development.

My intention is to allow writing tools that are integrated into Eclipse, while at the same time staying out of Eclipse plugin development as much as possible.

As one possible apporach, I'm thinking along the lines of some "generic" tooling plugin to which a Java application -- which gets run as a normal application being developed in the same Eclipse instance -- connects and "remote controls" the UI. This would require a one-time effort to build the generic plugin (including maintenance, of course), but development of the actual tools would happen outside of plugin development.

Now my question: What are the existing options towards such a generic plugin, as well as the more general problem of integrating with Eclipse without actually writing a plugin? The idea being that I wouldn't hesitate to build exactly that, but of course I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Your question is **way** too broad. It sounds like "me vision, but no plan; please instruct"; and that is not what SO is for.

Comment: I'm definitely NOT asking for instructions, but for existing components. If it turns out that there aren't any, writing said generic plugin is up to me, and that's not covered by this question. Sorry if that was not clear.